# MATCH() function can't locate hours

Tags: indexing, google-sheets, match

I've created a Time Sheet for my dog walkers to fill in. They enter `TIME STARTED` and `TIME ENDED` for each of their dog walks and then a `TOTAL TIME` is generated using the `=X-Y` formula. This `TOTAL TIME` is formatted to be displayed in `hh:mm` but its true `VALUE` is a long integer.

Using the `MATCH` and `INDEX` functions, I've set up a formula to match the `TOTAL TIME` value generated to an index on the "Payment Schedule" sheet and locate the respective payment.

I keep getting errors that state the total time `VALUES` can't be matched but I know that formatting isn't the issue and the values are clearly on the "Payment Schedule" sheet. And when the `MATCH` function does return a row it returns the incorrect row, which locates the incorrect payment/rate.

Here is [the Google Sheets I'm having trouble with](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NxDx4m8mAw7CEdF1bO4Uu5MT-zo8GkGZyuarkMfJopI/edit#gid=1809330546).

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer on another website:

> it's floating point rounding error on the time values.  I don't fully
>   understand what's happening, but I was able to reproduce it on my
>   system, and I found a work-around:  Change your formula to
>
> =INDEX(B:B, MATCH($I$4+TIME(0,0,1), A:A)) This adds one second (TIME(0,0,1); the arguments are TIME(hours,minutes,seconds)) to the I4
>   value; that seems to be enough to get it "over the hump", so that it
>   tests as being ≥ the value in A4 (or A7 or A10).  BTW, I tried
>   TIME(0,0,0.9), but apparently TIME() won't honor fractional seconds,
>   and so it just treats that as TIME(0,0,0); i.e., just plain zero.  If
>   you want to get a millisecond, you can use TIME(0,0,1)*0.001.

[link](https://superuser.com/questions/960916/index-match-function-returning-wrong-values)